# Ember js input binding not working

Tags: ember.js

This is the model that I have

```
App.Lecture = Ember.Model.extend({                                                  
    id: Ember.attr(),                                                               
    name: Ember.attr(),                                                             

    videoId: function(){                                                           
        return this.get('id');  

    }.property('id')                                                                
});
```

And I am trying to bind the model attribute id to my input in the template-

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lecture">
    {{input bind-attr value=videoId}}
</script>
```

But nothing is rendered. Whats the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you using Ember.Model. But [here is the link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qitog/1/edit) for a small example on binding a input value to a model property which is a computed property.

Below is the relevant code. The important thing to note is how to handle the computed property when called as a getter and setter.

```
App.Lecture = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: 0,
  name: '',
  videoId: function(key, value){
    if(value) {
      //setter
      this.set('id', value);
    } else {
      //getter
      return this.get('id');
    }
  }.property('id')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Lecture.create({id:1, name:'Blessan'});
  }
});

{{id}}: {{name}}
{{input valueBinding=videoId}}
```